# Scope of a variable cfr. Pluralsight C# test

Tags: c#, scope

I'm preparing for my microsoft exam about c# 70-483, *"still a long way to go"*
and following the C# path on pluralsight.
After doing the test and review my incorrect answers i came up to this one.

2.Consider the following code:

```
static void ListTowns(string[] countries)
 {
    foreach (string country in countries)
    {
        int townCount = GetTownCount(country);
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < townCount; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetTownName(country, i));
        }
    } 
}
```

When does the variable i go out of scope?
Answers:

1. On exiting the `ListTowns()` method.
2. On exiting the `foreach loop`
3. I never goes *out of scope* because the method is `static`.
4. On exiting the `for loop`

The Correct answer is 4, But my answer is 2.
Because after the for loop u still can use i.
Or is my definition of "out of scope" not correct?

Comment: Where is question?

Comment: after loop i variable again initialized is zero

Comment: When does the variable i go out of scope? sorry :)

Comment: answer 2 - after foreach, not for

Comment: @IgorSemin  after the for loop i is not again initialized to zero.

Comment: Indeed but why does pluralsight marks answer 4 as correct

Comment: after "for" loop and next iteration within foreach "i" will again be zero

Comment: Looks like it's a question designed to catch you out rather than test knowledge.  Upon exiting the for loop, the `foreach` loop will (potentially) iterate again, creating a new `i` variable.  So _technically_ it is going out of scope upon exiting the `for` loop (since it's not used again), before the next `foreach` iteration, as you've not actually exited the `foreach` yet.

Comment: In a next iteration "i" will be zero again but not after the for loop

Comment: @James Thorpe - Exactly my thoughts, many of Microsoft Certification Exam questions are designed that way...

Comment: @JayGould, I don't think that is a mistake, cause i is initialized in the foreach not in the for loop

Comment: @JamesThorpe: It's still in scope between the end of the `for` loop and the closing brace of the `foreach` loop. The fact that it's not used again doesn't mean it's out of scope.

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah I see.  I think I was getting at the fact that since the for is the last statement in the foreach, that's why it's the "correct" answer in the test. But I agree with your answer - ultimately it's a badly written question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question is vague and badly worded IMO. There's no such concept as a variable "going out of scope" in C# - but there *is* the scope of a variable, and the scope of the `i` variable is the whole of the `foreach` loop body, including the empty set of statements between the closing brace of the `for` loop and the closing brace of the `foreach` loop. The relevant part of the C# 5 specification is 3.7:

> The scope of a local variable declared in a local-variable-declaration (§8.5.1) is the block in which the declaration occurs. In this case, the block is the block of the `foreach` loop.

The fact that you can write

```
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

after the `for` loop and it still compiles shows it's still in scope. Each iteration of the `foreach` loop uses a different `i` variable, but everywhere within the `foreach` loop, `i` is in scope. (That's true even before its declaration - you can't use it, but it's still in scope.)

I'd have given the same answer as you, as the best approximation to what's being asked. I suggest you email Pluralsight to ask them to improve the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer 2 is correct.

I used the following code in Visual Studio

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         string[] testdata = { "one", "two", "three", "four"};
         ListCheckFunction(testdata);
         Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void ListCheckFunction(string[] countries)
    {
        foreach (string country in countries)
        {
            int townCount = countries.Count();
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < townCount; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(country + " " +i);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(i + " i is still in scope");
        }
    }
}
```

It gave me the following output

```
one 0
one 1
one 2
one 3
4 i is still in scope
two 0
two 1
two 2
two 3
4 i is still in scope
three 0
three 1
three 2
three 3
4 i is still in scope
four 0
four 1
four 2
four 3
4 i is still in scope
```